# Dynamodb re-order row priority field values and also make them sequential

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb, records has priority field. 1-N.
records shown to user with a form and user can update  priority field, it means I need to change the priority of the field.

one solution is like when priority of a record changed I  reorder all the records that their priory is more than it.

for example if I change a priority of  record in N= 5 to 10,  I need to order all records that their priority field is more than 5.

what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB store all items(records) in order by a tables sort-attribute. However, you are unable to update a key value, you would need to delete and add a new item every time you update.

One way to overcome this is to create a GSI. Depending on the throughput required for you table you may need to artificially shard the partition key. If you expect to consume less than 1000 WCU per second, you won't need to.

| gsipk | gsisk | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | data |
| 1 | 002 | data |
| 1 | 007 | data |
| 1 | 009 | data |

Now to get all the data in order of priority you simply `Query` your index where `gsipk` = 1.

You can also `Update` the order attribute `gsisk` without having to delete and put an item.